# Reverse org-cycle

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to unify my `org-mode` hotkeys with Workflowy's. In Workflowy, <kbd>C-↓</kbd> and <kbd>C-↑</kbd> will expand and collapse hierarchical structure respectively.

I want to mimic this behavior in `org-mode`. I know I can bind <kbd>C-↓</kbd> to `org-cycle`, but I cannot figure out how to reverse the behavior.

What can I do to `org-cycle` in reverse?

Answer (score 4):

The `org-cycle` command cycles between different states (folded, show children, show subtree, back to folded) so it isn't quite the same as having separate expand and collapse commands -- you don't need two key bindings since once expanded you can hit tab again to hide everything.

If you want to bind separate expand and collapse commands, you might use `org-show-subtree` as your expand command, and use `outline-hide-subtree` for the inverse operation. Note that those operate on the whole subtree so it's a bit different then `org-cycle` which allows you to show just the children before showing the whole tree. I don't think there are equivalent "partial expand, then full expand" and "partial collapse, then full collapse" commands so you might need to write your own based on `org-cycle`.

Comment: This does a nice job of addressing OP's actually need, but I think this would benefit from also answering his actual question.